# "Log on as a service" for a group doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I have a server that has a few services that run under different domain user accounts. If I create a group, add the user accounts to that group, and then add that group to the "Log on as a service" local security policy the services won't start but if I add the individual users under the "Log on as a service" local security policy the services will start.

Any idea on why a group wouldn't work?

- Windows 2008 R2
- AD 2008

Comment: This *should* work. Are you using a domain group or a local group? Are you sure che service accounts are members of this group? Have you checked the policy is actually applied and is not overriden by some GPO?

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how this would actually work. The service wouldn't actually be running under any user context. When I looked at this on one of my servers, Groups weren't a selectable object type. How did you add the group?

Comment: @Massimo, I agree, it should work but it doesn't. Domain group, yes the user is a member of the group, yes the policy is being applied and the group is showing up in the local policy settings.

Comment: @joeqwerty, I'm not trying to start the service with a group, I am starting the service with a user, I am adding that user to a group and then adding the group to the local security policy.

Comment: OK, got it. I had to reread the question.